# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unsqueeze'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

I'm running a training code using `pyhtorch` and `numpy`.

This is the `plot_example` function:

```py
def plot_example(low_res_folder, gen):
    files=os.listdir(low_res_folder)
    
    gen.eval()
    for file in files:
        image=Image.open("test_images/" + file)
        with torch.no_grad():
            upscaled_img=gen(
                config1.both_transform(image=np.asarray(image))["image"]
                .unsqueeze(0)
                .to(config1.DEVICE)
            )
        save_image(upscaled_img * 0.5 + 0.5, f"saved/{file}")
    gen.train()
```

The problem I have is that the `unsqueeze` attribute raises the error:

```
File "E:\Downloads\esrgan-tf2-masteren\modules\train1.py", line 58, in train_fn
    plot_example("test_images/", gen)
    
File "E:\Downloads\esrgan-tf2-masteren\modules\utils1.py", line 46, in plot_example
    config1.both_transform(image=np.asarray(image))["image"]
    
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'unsqueeze'
```

The network is GAN network and `gen()` represents the Generator.

Comment: `unsqueeze()` is for `torch.tensor` object. It does not exist in Numpy. Here in your code you are trying to unsqueeze a numpy `numpy.ndarray`: `image=np.asarray(image))["image"].unsqueeze(0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure image is a tensor in the shape of [batch size, channels, height, width] before entering any Pytorch layers.

Here you have
`image=np.asarray(image)`

I would remove this numpy conversion and keep it a torch.tensor.

Or if you really want it to be a numpy array, then right before it enters your generator make sure to use `torch.from_numpy()` as shown in this documentation on your numpy image before it gets unsqueezed: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.from_numpy.html

This function is ofcourse an alternative if you don't want to get rid of that original conversion.

Sarthak Jain